# Is creating multiple instances of a class dynamically good practice? Alternatives?

Tags: python, class, oop, data-structures

## Background

I'm working with API calls that return network element data (telecommunications industry fyi).

I'm dynamically creating 'x' number of class instances based on a 'meta' response from the api, that tells me how many of such elements I'm querying exist in the network. This is not something I can know beforehand (may be 1 element, may be 10, 100 etc).

Now each element has several possible attributes (name, lat/long, ip_address, MAC, type.... etc) hence why I thought a class structure would be best. This is my first time using Classes.

### Question

Is this best practice? What are the alternatives to this approach?

### Code

```
# Update the Node class's 'num_nodes' class level variable
Node.get_number_of_nodes()

# Create 'x' amount of Node instances and store in a list, based on 'num_nodes'
nodes = [Node() for x in range(Node.num_nodes)]

# Grab unique node ids and assign to the instances of Node
[node.get_node_ids() for node in nodes]
```

```
class Node:
    """
    A class to represent a network node.
    """

    # Shared class variables
    num_nodes = 0

    # Shared class instances
    session = Session()

    @classmethod
    def get_number_of_nodes(cls):
        """
        Api call to ### which fetches number of nodes metadata
        """
        path = "####"
        url = f"{cls.session.HOST}{path}"
        headers = {'Authorization': #####,}
        params = {'limit': 10000,}

        resp = request(
            "GET", url, headers=headers, params=params, verify=False
        )
        resp = resp.text.encode('utf8')
        resp = json.loads(resp)

        cls.num_nodes = resp['meta']['total']

    def get_node_ids(self):
        """
        For an instance of Node, get its attributes from ###.
        """
        pass
```

Comment: I wouldn’t modify the class attribute because what if you wanted to create two collections of nodes in future? Instead of a class method to get the number of nodes and then separately creating them, use a class method which is a factory that creates and returns the list of nodes.

Comment: Thanks @barny I'll look into factories now and answer back here how I get on

Comment: I agree with @barny. Beside other things, classes are made exactly for dynamic creation of instances. You usually instantiate with `ClassName()` that invokes `ClassName.__init__()`, but you can also add other class methods that act as a factory, returning a `ClassName` instance (or even a collection of instances). For alternatives, maybe you want to have `Network` instances containing a list of `Node`s, and move the `Node` managing out of the `Node` class, and into the `Network` (apart from the `Node.id`, that each Node still stores).